# Search xml for a value using sed

Tags: sed, xml-parsing, ksh

I have a below xml file

```
<documents>
<document><title>some title1</title><abstract>Some abstract1</abstract></document>
<document><title>some title2</title><abstract>Some abstract2</abstract></document>
<document><title>some title3</title><abstract>Some abstract3</abstract></document>
<document><title>some title4</title><abstract>Some abstract4</abstract></document>
</documents>
```

I am trying to write a ksh script to fetch the abstract value based on title=title4

xmllint , xstartlet is not allowed in my machine (access issues)

I have tried with

```
sed -n '/abstract/{s/.*<abstract>//;s/<\/abstract.*//;p;}' connections.xml
```

How to modify this to search based on a title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example you have given:

```
sed -n '/title>.*title4<\/title>/{s#.*<abstract>##;s#</abstract>.*##;p}' file
```

Will give you:

```
Some abstract4
```

Comment: After some edit , the below code works sed -n '/title>.*title4<\/title>/{s#.*<abstract>##;s#</abstract>.*##;p;}' documents.xml

Answer (score 0):

***grep*** approach:

```
grep -Poz '<title>.*?title4</title><abstract>\K[^<>]+(?=</abstract>)' connections.xml && echo ""
```

The output:

```
Some abstract4
```

Comment: grep: illegal option -- P
grep: illegal option -- o
grep: illegal option -- z
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: @useranon, you have pretty poor environment: no grep, no xmlstarlet. My deepest condolences for you ...